# GraphQL Dataloader - Global variable with load() function

Tags: graphql

I'm using graphql with dataloader. I have this call inside a type. My problem is that when I call "categoryPhotoLoader" I want to pass user_id as a global param for every _id. Is this possible, or I have to create a concat (`${_id}_${user_id}`) and get inside the dataloader the first user_id of the keys? (split the string and get the user_id part of the first id)

```
async photoS3({_id, user_id}, _, {categoryPhotoLoader}) {
    return categoryPhotoLoader.load(`${_id}_${user_id}`);
}
```

I would like something like that

```
async photoS3({_id, user_id}, _, {categoryPhotoLoader}) {
    return categoryPhotoLoader.load(_id, {user_id: user_id});
}
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to use multiple values as a key? It's unclear what a "global param" is or what global variables have to do with the use case you're describing.

Comment: think that I want all the ids of a specific user. I can pass the id.... but I want also to pass the user_id.

Answer (score 2):

Dataloader keys do not have to be Strings, they can be Arrays, Objects or other data types. So you can do:

```
categoryPhotoLoader.load({ _id, user_id })
```

and this Object will be passed to your batch function. If you do this, you'll want to provide a `cacheKeyFn` to your Loader's constructor so that dataloader can tell when two keys are equivalent. In this case, it would be simple enough to do something like:

new DataLoader(batchLoadFn, {
  cacheKeyFn: ({ _id, user_id }) => `${_id}${user_id}`,
})

Be wary of using `JSON.stringify` since you want to ensure the correct order of properties in the string.